# Merge values from Array into a String

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to append some items from an Array into a string but struggling somewhat.  I have an array via the following

```
this.$root.data[1].arrayOfObjects;
```

This array looks something like this

```
(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
    0:
        label: "Value1"
        name: "Value 1"
        value: 1
    1:
        label: "Value2"
        name: "Value 2"
        value: 2
```

The array could be empty, or it could contain multiple objects.  What I am trying to do is merge the values from the name keys from each object in the array into a string, seperated by a comma.  So for the above, I expect to be returned

```
"Value 1, Value 2"
```

So I was thinking about first assigning the array

```
const array = this.$root.data[1].arrayOfObjects;
```

I was then thinking about looping it

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {

}
```

This however is where I get lost.  I know I could potentially use some ES6 features like map or filter, but not sure how to apply to this?

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the wwamted property `name` and join the array to a string.

Methods:

- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the property `name`,
- [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with a custom *glue*.

Code:

```
result = this.$root.data[1].arrayOfObjects
    .map(({ name }) => name)
    .join(', ');
```